# Flutter: RichText with darktheme

Tags: flutter, darkmode, flutter-text

I use some `RichText` throughout my application to switch colors between text and display widgets in between.

E.g.

```
RichText(
 text: TextSpan(text: 'text1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black), 
 children: [
   WidgetSpan(alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle, child: SomeWidget()),
   TextSpan(text: 'text2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
   WidgetSpan(alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle, child: Icon(Icons.someIcon)),
   TextSpan(text: 'text3'),
  ]
));
```

The problem now is that when switching to dark mode, the black test is contrasted to a black background and thus invisible. The regular `Text('some text')` widget will automatically display black by default but will become white in dark mode. How can I achieve the same or something similar when using `RichtText`?

Answer (score 2):

Well you defined your `RichText` like this:

`TextSpan(text: 'text1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)`

As you know the `color` argument that you pass to a Widget has the highest priority, therefore, your `TextSpan` will always be black.

---

One solution is instead of hardcoding the color you can do this:

```dart
Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.color
```

If we look at the definition of this `theme` it looks like this:

```dart
/// The default text style for [Material].
TextStyle? get bodyText2 => bodyMedium;
```

If you use this approach your `TextSpan` and normal `Text` widgets should have the same color. In general one should always prefer working with `themes` over hardcoding colors. If your user switches to dark mode the theme will switch too and therefore, all styles should be switched correctly as well.